# How to use FuzzyRowFilter to fetch time series data

Tags: java, hbase

I have a table, where I'll be storing event data. Possibly, billions of records a day.

Here is the structure of my rowKey:

```
salt_bucket-clientUUID-eventUUID-timestamp-timeUUID
```

- `salt_bucket` is used to avoid region hot spotting; is `1 byte` that maps to my number of regions.
- `clientUUID. 16 bytes`;
- `eventUUID. 16 bytes`;
- `timestamp` will be floored to the nearest time bucket (1 hour, 30 minutes or even more granular time period). `8 bytes`;
- `timeUUID` - UUID of version 1 used to guarantee uniqueness of my record, to prevent upserts. `16 bytes`;

In my client Java app I want to perform a range scan. As an input parameter will be given `timeWindow` (start and end date), `clientUUID` and `eventUUID`.

I thought that the best candidate for this job would be `FuzzyRowFilter`. It allows to use byte mask on the row key. So that I'll be doing exact match on `clientId` and `eventId` components of the row key, whilst leaving ?s for `salt_bucket` and `timeUUID`.

**Q:But what do I do with my time range? How do I make `FuzzyRowFilter` to honor my time window, so that I can refine my scan operation?**